# Адаптация ширины блоков через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. для того чтобы был адаптивным сайт нужно указывать  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, но меня устраивает так как выглядит сайт,единственное что на компьютере меню отображается нормально,а вот через телефон меню выгляди так как будто некоторые блоки заехали друг на друга.по этому использовать @media что бы подогнать меню с помощью css не получится. есть ли вариант применять стиль если разрешение экрана например 320 px через JS?

Comment: Вы через JS можете в любой момент выполнения менять мета тег `meta name="viewport" ` - и оно будет работать. Например можно делать адаптивный viewport, но но ловить `onresize`, и если ширина меньше, например 490px менять параметр на `content="width=490px, initial-scale=1.0"`

Comment: да.но у меня неадаптивный сайт, тоесть все блоки поразьезжаются. нужно лишь только меню подправить и все

Comment: а, понятно, что-то прочитал плохо. Ну значит у вас используется что-то не кроссбраузерное, или что-то из новинок css/html: надо отлаживать: в вопросе данных недостаточно, может быть что угодно. Если телефон старый - то это норма, можно для таких выдавать сообщение типа "браузер не поддерживатеся скачай новый" :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var window_width = $(window).width();
  if (window_width < 600) {
    $("#block").width(200);
    $('#block').removeClass('block_big').addClass('block_small');
  } else {
    $("#block").width(500);
    $('#block').removeClass('block_small').addClass('block_big');
  };
});
```

```css
#block {
  height: 200px;
}

.block_big {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.block_small {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Изменяем размер окна:</p>
<div id="block" class="block_big"></div>
```